# Change Position of native keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

In my application i am using Tab activities to switch from one activity to another.

**I want to know that is there any way to change our native android keyboard position? Because i want to display native keyboard above Tab that i have used in my application ?**

Thus user can easily navigate while typing.

[image]

```
I have searched a lot but i didn't get any success yet. Any help would be appreciated.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know that is there any way to change our native android keyboard position?

No.

> Because i want to display native keyboard above Tab that i have used in my application ?

[Do not use bottom tab bars](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

Comment: Bah... I wish there was a way to change it's position!  Touchpad issues here :/

Comment: @Selah. Can you provide the solution for change the position?

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute into your activity. This will show your tabs upside the keyboard.

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"